# eclipse opening X11 Window

Tags: eclipse, x11

I wanted to see how the code of [FFMpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) works. So what I did is imported this project in eclipse. When I run the binary from the command line, it decodes the entire video without any problem and displays it as well. However if I run exactly same binary from the eclipse, it fails. It fails when the binary executes the following statement -

`instance->display = XOpenDisplay (NULL);`

Can anyone tell if there is any special requirement for running X11 apps in eclipse? I have linked the necessary libraries in the code. Also the binary works perfectly from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem developing with ROOT gui classes.
I solved the issue adding the env variable DISPLAY to :0 in the run configuration tab.